# Why am i getting this Non-Object Error when tring to use laravel helper kebab case?

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-7, laravel-controller

I wanted  to turn the package name into url name as well So when i used laravel helpers inside where() in my controller method i get an error:
[image]

My Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

    public function package($package){
        $converted = Packages::where('Package_Name',$package)->first(); 
        $package = Str::kebab($converted);
        return view('pages.package',[
            'package' => $package,
        ]);
    }
```

My Model:

```
class Packages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'packages';

    protected $fillable = ['Package_Banner_Image','Package_Image','Package_Type','Package_Name','Package_Short_Description','Package_Price','Package_Duration','Package_Level','Package_Location'];
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::prefix('/packages')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'PackageController@packages')->name('packages');
    Route::get('/{package}', 'PackageController@package')->name('packages.show');
});
```

My Migration:

```
        Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Package_Banner_Image');
            $table->string('Package_Image');
            $table->string('Package_Type');
            $table->string('Package_Name')->unique();
            $table->integer('Package_Price');
            $table->integer('Package_Duration');
            $table->string('Package_Level');
            $table->string('Package_Short_Description');
            $table->longText('Package_Location');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

two things.
first: validate that $converted is not null, that found a record.
second: change the order to your routes, put first routes whit params, after static routes, and put the model name in your param.

In your case the order change of routes could be the solution

update your code whit this

```
public function package($package){
    $converted = Packages::where('Package_Name',$package)->first(); 
    if($converted){
        $package = Str::kebab($converted->Package_Name);
        return view('pages.package',[
            'package' => $converted,
        ]);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: i tried all this when i do not use Str::kebab(); it works just fine but when i use it this error is shown.

Comment: in the documentation [https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-kebab-case]  `$converted = Str::kebab('fooBar');` the parameter is string and you send an Object

Comment: how do i fix that?

Comment: 1. validate if the sql is found a record, 2. send as parameter the object title `$converted->title` or other property, and last you need send the object in your view `return view('pages.package',[
            'package' => $converted,
        ]);`

Comment: do you mean my packages method in the controller?

Comment: I have added above

Comment: it works but it even if i write suppose one of my package name is Kathmandu Pokhara so even if i write http://127.0.0.1:8000/packages/Kathmandu%20Pokhara it still works

Comment: ok, so you need use the kebab method when you redirect, for example `<a href="/packages/{{Illuminate\Support\Str::kebab($package->Package_Name)}}"> package </a>`

Comment: i think the answer you above is not working check it at: https://realadventurenepal.herokuapp.com/

Comment: my last answer is only an example, check the correct path and change for your variables name

Comment: i did not mean the last answer i mean the answer at the top the kebab case is not working because i have kept kebab case in the a tag in packages pages to redirect and it does not work but try using package_name in url check at the site.